# rails + MySQL on OSX(Yosemite)

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, osx-yosemite

I was running an old rails project on ruby-1.9.3-p125 until i updated mysql. 
I ended up removing & reinstalling mysql via homebrew in order to fix issues. I managed to recover the enviroments of all my php projects but not this one.

running ps aux | grep mysql returns:

```
myuser           19131   0,0  0,1  3570856   6428   ??  S     1:30μμ   0:11.46 /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/lib/plugin --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --log-error=/usr/local/var/mysql/Macbook.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/Macbook.local.pid
myuser           19039   0,0  0,0  2447704    480   ??  S     1:30μμ   0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql
myuser           27974   0,0  0,0  2423356    208 s001  R+    1:22μμ   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn mysql
```

When i try to run rake db:create i get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::SECURE_CONNECTION
```

mysql.server status seems to be running.. when i try to stop (mysql.server stop) i get:

```
Shutting down MySQL
.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/macbook.local.pid).
```

And mysql continue to run but with a new pid id .

Any idea whats wrong with the rails project and how to approach it?

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your mysql2 gem.

First of all, check your `Gemfile` includes `gem 'mysql2'` and not the older `mysql` gem

Next, run `bundle update mysql2` if you didn't need to change your gemfile, or `bundle install` if you did. Only run `bundle update` (without the `mysql2` part) if you're sure updating the other gems wont affect anything.

Then try running your rake command.

Comment: Hi Jon, mysql2 is used and not mysql. Did the update as you suggested and now the rake command returns : dlopen(/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mailcatcher/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users....gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
  Reason: Incompatible library version: nokogiri.bundle requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0 - /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mailcatcher/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle

Comment: How did you install libxml2? Hopefully you used homebrew ... In which case update it through homebrew and then update or reinstall nokogiri. You might also have the same issue with libxslt.